# pgfplots: conditional 'inner sep' for axis label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

How can I set the `inner sep` of the `xlabel` to `0pt` if it is `empty` and not `xlabel=<text>`?

I mean sth. like 
`\ifx\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel} \empty inner sep=0pt \else 5pt\fi`

[image: lots]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
xlabel=\empty,  ylabel=\empty, % "default"
every axis x label/.append style={
%inner sep=0pt
},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={anchor=west, fill=yellow, minimum width=1cm}
]
\begin{axis}[
clip=false, 
ylabel={The y Label},
every axis label/.append style={draw}, 
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-5) (1,1) (2,2)};

\node[mystyle] (xl) {xlabel: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel}};
\node[mystyle, above of=xl] {ylabel: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```latex
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis x label/.append code={%
    \protected@edef\zzz{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel}}%
    \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\zzz}
      {\pgfkeysalso{inner sep=0pt}}
      {\pgfkeysalso{inner sep=5pt}}%
  },
}
```

This tests if the x label is *blank* (precisely: empty or containing only spaces after `\protected@edef` expansion). If you really want blank-but-non-empty x labels to have the `5pt` inner sep like other non-empty x labels, simply use `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrempty` macro instead of `\ifblank`. The difference between these can be seen using, for instance, `xlabel={\space}`.

Since `\ifblank` (as well as `\ifstrempty`) is fully expandable, this can also be written this way:

```latex
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis x label/.append code={%
    \protected@edef\zzz{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel}}%
    \pgfkeysalso{inner sep/.expanded={%
      \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\zzz}{0}{5}pt}}%
  },
}
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
  xlabel=\empty,  ylabel=\empty, % "default"
  every axis x label/.append code={%
  \protected@edef\zzz{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel}}%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\zzz}
    {\pgfkeysalso{inner sep=0pt}}
    {\pgfkeysalso{inner sep=5pt}}%
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% First plot with blank x label
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mystyle/.style={anchor=west, fill=yellow, minimum width=1cm}
  ]
\begin{axis}[
  clip=false,
  ylabel={The y Label},
  every axis label/.append style={draw},
  ]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-5) (1,1) (2,2)};

\node[mystyle] (xl) {xlabel: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel}};
\node[mystyle, above of=xl] {ylabel: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
% Second plot with non-blank x label
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mystyle/.style={anchor=west, fill=yellow, minimum width=1cm}
  ]
\begin{axis}[
  clip=false,
  xlabel={Non blank label},
  ylabel={The y Label},
  every axis label/.append style={draw},
  ]
\addplot coordinates {(0,-5) (1,1) (2,2)};

\node[mystyle] (xl) {xlabel: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xlabel}};
\node[mystyle, above of=xl] {ylabel: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ylabel}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, helps me good. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. I did a minor change (using `\pgfkeysalso`) and  added another way.